# Visual Studio for Mac, how to debug solution load failure?

Tags: visual-studio

VS version: Visual Studio for Mac 17.5,
OS: macOS Monterey Version 12.6.3,
Hardware: Mac mini (Late 2014)

This solution is for an iPhone and Android application that I maintain.  When I attempt to load my solution that previously worked, I see the following error.

Could not load solution:/users/sepp/svn/myApp/myApp.sln
Load operation failed.

My solution file has not changed for 4 months.
The project paths within the solution seem to be correct:  “iOS\myApp.iOS.csproj”, “Droid\myApp.Droid.csproj”, and “myApp\myApp.csproj”.  They haven’t changed in several years.

How do I debug this?
How do I find more information about what is happening?  Is there a log file? If so where?
Is there a way to comment out sections of the solutions file to see what section is causing the failure?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (1) Please share the full and exact error message. (2) Try moving away the `.userprefs` file (if you have one) and start VS. (3) The log is two files called by default `ActivityLog.xml` and `ActivityLog.xsl`. The first contains the activity log data and the second is an XML style sheet which provides a more convenient way to view the XML file.

Comment: That was the complete message, except the application name is not actually myApp. It is not a very helpful message.  This is an app targeting both iPhone and Android. I removed all the Android sections from the solution file and now it loads.  So, there is something wrong with the Android sections.
  I do not have a .userprefs file.

Comment: Just to help others, the .userprefs file is in the hidden directory .vs.  It took me a while to find it.